# Breakdown year in weeks - Java 8

Tags: java-8

I want to create a "select", that when selecting a year in another "select", I load all the weeks of that year, from Monday to Friday:

Example, if I select 2018 my "select" would be something like this.

1 - 01/01/18 - 07/01/18

2 - 01/08/18 - 01/14/18

3 - 15/01/18 - 01/21/10

......

52 - 12/24/18 - 12/30/18

The data was prepared in the back-end with java. To then send it as an array of string to the front-end

Comment: ok, so where's the problem? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Did you try anything ? where is your finding?

Comment: Yes, I have the weeks of the year. It would be a loop and I do not know if I can extract from "X" week of the year, Monday and Sunday. For example, if I have 2018 and week 4, know that week 4 starts on January 22 and ends on January 28.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

public class Weeks {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int year = 2018;
    int weeks = getNumWeeksForYear(year);

    for (int i = 1; i < weeks; i++) {

        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.clear();
        calendar.set(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR, i);
        calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);

        Date monday = calendar.getTime();
        calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 6);
        Date sunday = calendar.getTime();
        System.out.println("week" + i);
        System.out.println(monday);
        System.out.println(sunday);
    }

}

public static int getNumWeeksForYear(int year) {
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    c.set(year, 0, 1);
    return c.getMaximum(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR);
}

}
```

Comment: FYI… These terrible date-time classes (`Date`, `Calendar`, etc.) have been supplanted by the modern *java.time* classes built into Java 8 and later.

Answer (score 1):

## Avoid legacy date-time classes

The modern solution uses *java.time* classes. These supplanted the terribly flawed legacy classes such as `Date` & `Calendar`.

## Looping

Determine the first day of year. And the first day of the following year, as our limit.

```java
Year year = Year.of( 2018 );
LocalDate firstOfYear = year.atDay( 1 );
LocalDate firstOfFollowingYear = year.plusYears( 1 ).atDay( 1 );
```

Use a `TemporalAdjuster` to move through time. The `TemporalAdjusters` class (note the plural) happens to offer an adjuster implementation for our needs, `previousOrSame`. Use that to move back in time to get a Monday, if the 1st of year is not already Monday.

```java
TemporalAdjuster adjuster = TemporalAdjusters.previousOrSame( DayOfWeek.MONDAY );
LocalDate firstMondayOfYear = firstOfYear.with( adjuster );
```

Define a list to hold our weekly report.

```
List < String > weeks = new ArrayList <>( 53 );
```

Define a formatter to generate the text for our weekly report. The `DateTimeFormatter` class can automatically localize, so we need not hard-code a specific format.

```java
Locale locale = Locale.forLanguageTag( "es-ES" ); // Spain locale.
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDate( FormatStyle.SHORT ).withLocale( locale );
```

Loop through the weeks of the year. We increment one week at a time, until hitting the following year.

```java
int nthWeekOfYear = 0;
LocalDate localDate = firstMondayOfYear;
while ( localDate.isBefore( firstOfFollowingYear ) ) {
    nthWeekOfYear++;
    String output = nthWeekOfYear + " - " + localDate.format( formatter ) + " - " + localDate.plusDays( 6 ); // Using Fully-Closed weeks, where both beginning and end are inclusive. In contrast to Half-Open.
    weeks.add( output );
    // Set up next loop.
    localDate = localDate.plusWeeks( 1 );
}
```

Convert from a `List` to an array, per your directions in the Question.

```
String[] results = weeks.toArray( new String[ weeks.size() ] );
```

Dump to console.

```
System.out.println( "results = " + Arrays.toString( results ) );
```

## Streams

We could rewrite this code by using streams and lambdas. This requires Java 9+.

The [`LocalDate#datesUntil`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDate.html#datesUntil(java.time.LocalDate,java.time.Period)) method produces a [`Stream`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html) of `LocalDate` objects.

While I do not necessarily recommend this code, I found it interesting that we can write the entire routine as a one-liner.

```java
int inputYear = 2018;
List < String > weeks =
        Year
                .of( inputYear )
                .atDay( 1 )
                .with( TemporalAdjusters.previousOrSame( DayOfWeek.MONDAY ) )
                .datesUntil( Year.of( inputYear ).plusYears( 1 ).atDay( 1 ) , Period.ofWeeks( 1 ) )
                .map( localDate -> localDate.format( DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDate( FormatStyle.SHORT ).withLocale( Locale.forLanguageTag( "es-ES" ) ) ) + " - " + localDate.plusDays( 6 ).format( DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDate( FormatStyle.SHORT ).withLocale( Locale.forLanguageTag( "es-ES" ) ) ) )
                .toList();  // Before Java 16, change to .collect( Collectors.toList()); or .collect( Collectors.toUnmodifiableList());
```

When run.

> weeks = [1/1/18 - 7/1/18, 8/1/18 - 14/1/18, 15/1/18 - 21/1/18, 22/1/18 - 28/1/18, 29/1/18 - 4/2/18, 5/2/18 - 11/2/18, 12/2/18 - 18/2/18, 19/2/18 - 25/2/18, 26/2/18 - 4/3/18, 5/3/18 - 11/3/18, 12/3/18 - 18/3/18, 19/3/18 - 25/3/18, 26/3/18 - 1/4/18, 2/4/18 - 8/4/18, 9/4/18 - 15/4/18, 16/4/18 - 22/4/18, 23/4/18 - 29/4/18, 30/4/18 - 6/5/18, 7/5/18 - 13/5/18, 14/5/18 - 20/5/18, 21/5/18 - 27/5/18, 28/5/18 - 3/6/18, 4/6/18 - 10/6/18, 11/6/18 - 17/6/18, 18/6/18 - 24/6/18, 25/6/18 - 1/7/18, 2/7/18 - 8/7/18, 9/7/18 - 15/7/18, 16/7/18 - 22/7/18, 23/7/18 - 29/7/18, 30/7/18 - 5/8/18, 6/8/18 - 12/8/18, 13/8/18 - 19/8/18, 20/8/18 - 26/8/18, 27/8/18 - 2/9/18, 3/9/18 - 9/9/18, 10/9/18 - 16/9/18, 17/9/18 - 23/9/18, 24/9/18 - 30/9/18, 1/10/18 - 7/10/18, 8/10/18 - 14/10/18, 15/10/18 - 21/10/18, 22/10/18 - 28/10/18, 29/10/18 - 4/11/18, 5/11/18 - 11/11/18, 12/11/18 - 18/11/18, 19/11/18 - 25/11/18, 26/11/18 - 2/12/18, 3/12/18 - 9/12/18, 10/12/18 - 16/12/18, 17/12/18 - 23/12/18, 24/12/18 - 30/12/18, 31/12/18 - 6/1/19]

A little more reasonable would be extracting the formatter and the `Year`.

```java
Locale locale = Locale.forLanguageTag( "es-ES" ); // Spain locale.
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDate( FormatStyle.SHORT ).withLocale( locale );

Year year = Year.of( 2018 );
List < String > weeks =
        year
                .atDay( 1 )
                .with( TemporalAdjusters.previousOrSame( DayOfWeek.MONDAY ) )
                .datesUntil( year.plusYears( 1 ).atDay( 1 ) , Period.ofWeeks( 1 ) )
                .map( localDate -> localDate.format( formatter ) + " - " + localDate.plusDays( 6 ).format( formatter ) )
                .toList();  // Before Java 16, change to .collect( Collectors.toList()); or .collect( Collectors.toUnmodifiableList());
```

## ISO 8601

If your definition of week complies with the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) [definition of week](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date):

- First day of week is Monday
- Week # 1 of year contains the first Thursday of the calendar year

… then I suggest adding the [`ThreeTen-Extra`](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) library to your project to utilize the [`YearWeek`](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org.threeten.extra/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html) class.